# Should web api for placing order also handle user creation?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an API for web store. There are some several consumers of this API, who have possibility to create users and place orders.
One of the consumers has suggested to merge two api calls, let's say `/user/create` and `/order/create` into one.
From this:

```
POST /user/create {name: 'John', email: 'john@example.org'}

POST /order/create {basket: [...], user_id: 12938}
```

To this:

```
POST /order/create 
{
    user: {name: 'John', email: 'john@example.org'}, 
    basket: [...]
}
```

It seems to me that this reduces flexibility and increases complexity of handling errors (if such email already exists, for example)

What a pros/cons of the solution? Are there some common standards for such kind of API?

Comment: does my answer solves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I see no pros for such architecture mistake, beside the single one - client's logic will be simpler, since it sends only one query and just doesn't care. But this is a short-sighted as well - the client will have to handle different errors.

Cons:

- These are completely different resources - should be separated.
- More difficult to test - you need to handle various testing scenarios. It's easy to overlook one.
- What about exceptions and HTTP codes? An order is sent and you get *Email already taken* error - WTF? What status code should it have?
- This kind of a solution may suit  only the single client what about else?

Are there any standards? Basically no, REST isn't a standard but an architectural style. However if you deliver an API that will be used by multiple clients you should stick to REST rules as much as possible unless you have a good excuse for obeying these rules. I don't see such an excuse here.